# Access a Shape's Characters Object

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code which works fine.

```
With Selection.ShapeRange(1).TextFrame2.TextRange
    With .Characters(i, n - i).Font
        .Size = 10
        .Bold = False
    End With
End with
```

But this code leaves the shape selected, showing its various handles. So, I tried to select a cell on the sheet but that doesn't deselect the shape, at least not while ScreenUpdating is False. In fact, selecting the shape by VBA doesn't deactivate the ActiveCell. Perhaps I should try `Activate` - too many variations for a second rate solution.

The better solution would be to not Select the shape in the first place. The reason I select it is because I didn't find a way to access the shape's own Characters object. Both of the following return the text.

```
? activesheet.shapes(1).textframe.characters.text and
? activesheet.shapes(1).oleformat.object.text
```

But all my attempts with variations of the following fail. Should I try the simple Mid$() function?

```
? activesheet.shapes(1).oleformat.object.characters(1,10)
```

So, in summary, I either need to access individual characters in the shape and manipulate them without using the Selection object or find a way to get rid of the Selection after it has done its job.

BTW, the entire shape is created on the fly. As things are, I first set the Text property (in the code preceding the above snippet) and then modify some of the characters. I could use another method, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without selecting:

```
Dim shp As Shape
Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(1)

With shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, n - i).Font
    .Size = 10
    .Bold = False
End With
```

Or just:

```
With ActiveSheet.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(i, n - i).Font
```

Comment: Thank you! `Characters(i, n - 1)` crashes but `Characters(i, n - 2)` does not. So now I have another tree to bark up at. That looks a lot easier :-)

Comment: Oops I mistook the `n - i` in your snippet for `n - 1`... fixed.